# Javascript: allow methods of object passed as an argument access to public methods

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Apologies if the title isn't quite clear :)

I'm passing an object `O` (that has methods) to a function `A` (that has private functions and public methods). Can I give `O` the capacity to call any of `A`'s methods?

So:

```
var O = {
        O_method1: function (text) {
            return A_public1(text);
        }
    },
    A = (function (O) {
        function A_private1(text) {
            return O.O_method1(text);
        }
        return {
            A_public1: function (text) {
                return text + " else";
            },
            A_public2: function (text) {
                return A_private1(text);
            } 
        };
    }(O));

alert (A.A_public2("something"));
```

So here, `A` receives `O` as an argument. The call to `A_public2` calls `A_private1`, which calls `O_method1` that has been received as an argument into `A`. No problem so far. However, `O_method1` tries to call `A_public1`, but it can't see it. How can I enable this last call?

The error in Firebug is: `ReferenceError: A_public1 is not defined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your definition of `O_method1`, you're calling a method that belongs to A, without referencing A. If you change the definition of `O_method1` to:

```
O_method1: function (text) {
  return A.A_public1(text);
}
```

It will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this. It doesn't totally solve my real-world problem, but it's totally the right solution here :)

Comment: No problem. What is your real world issue?